# Edit user informations by office365 panel

Tags: azure, office365

I have almost 200 office365 accounts and i installed AD Sync service, after i installed this service i cant change any user information by Office 365 panel, everything is disabled.

[image]

I can click on button "Definir como principal/Set as Default" because it is disabled. I can't add another alias because it's disabled too.

This user is trying to access your account and get following error:

```
Sua conta foi bloqueada temporariamente para evitar uso não autorizado

english: Your account was blocked temporaly to avoid not authorized access
```